# How to count the length of a word in a sentence using python

Tags: python

I want to count the length of a word in a sentence

Input: `Hi Hello How Are You`
Output: `2 5 3 3 3`

```py
s=input("Enter the sentence:\n")
a=list(map(len, s.split()))
print(a)
```

I already tried this code which in fact returns the correct output but it's a list
i.e-
Input-Hi Hello
Output-[2,5]

I don't want it as a list, I want it as
Input-Hi Hello
Expected Output- 2 5

Comment: after all that code, just do `print(' '.join(map(str, a)))`

Answer (score 7):

This should give you what you need:

```
s=input('Enter a sentence: ')
print(*map(len, s.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = "Hello how are you"

for word in sentence.split(' '):
    print(len(word))
```

Here a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

The join function along with map may help to print the list like this

```
s=input("Enter the sentence:\n")
a=list(map(len, s.split()))
print(" ".join(map(str, a)))
```

as the map functon heps in converting elements to string and join to separate the using space.